# Why can I not select my RDS database when trying to set up a RDS proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I am facing an issue while setup the RDS proxy. I have set up RDS Mysql t3.small but when I am going to ad rds instance in RSS proxy target section it doesn't show there though rds instance is available.

[image]

anyone facing issue like this.

Please guide me if I missed anything

Comment: Have you already reviewed the limitations here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For your kind information MySQL 8.0 doesn't support RDS proxy.  You need to use older version 5.7 MySQL.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from where? Do you have a reference or link for it?

Comment: Reference link:
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Comment: From [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): "Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."

Answer (score 0):

**Either you are on an unsupported version of MySQL or `read_only` is set to 1 (`true`) in the DB parameter group.**

According to the [Amazon RDS Proxy User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy.limits), you can't use RDS Proxy with RDS for MySQL 8.0.

RDS Proxy currently only supports MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.

Double-check to see if your database is not set to read-only or is on an unsupported version of MySQL.